# Dart: trying to write to file, always get empty file

Tags: dart

I'm just trying to write some text to a file. But for some reason I always get a blank file created. Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void run(String? mystr) async {
  var fileName = "output.txt";
  await File(fileName).writeAsString(mystr!);
}

main() {
  while (true) {
    stdout.write(">");
    var line = stdin.readLineSync();
    run(line);
  }
}
```

I've read the dart documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/3.2.6/dart-io/File-class.html), but for some reason, it's not working. The file "output.txt" does get created, but it's always blank with nothing in it.

Comment: change the return type of `run` to `Future<void>` and do `await run(line)` so that you finish writing before you loop around again.

Comment: Additionally you must check that `line` is not `null` first.  There's a reason that `readLineSync` returns a nullable type!  You also should call `writeLine` (or `writeLineSync`) with `flush: true` if you want a stronger guarantee that the changes will be reflected on disk when it returns.

Answer (score 0):

a few things:

- `writeAsString` should be using mode `FileMode.append`
- `run` should return a `Future<void>`
- `run` should be `await`ed in `main` (which means `main` should be `async`)
- it would be good practice to check that `readLineSync` is not returning `null`

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> run(String mystr) async {
  var fileName = "output.txt";
  await File(fileName).writeAsString(mystr, mode: FileMode.append);
}

void main() async {
  while (true) {
    stdout.write(">");
    var line = stdin.readLineSync();
    if (line == null) return;
    await run(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: well, "writeAsString should be using mode FileMode.append" may be an unnecessary step - but feel free to experiment with the other parts